# pgfplots axis description near arrow for non boxed axes

Tags: pgfplots

In PGFPlots, I'd like to set the default axis description location near the arrow for non boxed axes and otherwise keep the existing default of placing the axis description halfway between both ends of the axis. For example, take the following code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\pgfplotsset{%
  every axis x label/.style={%
    at={(ticklabel cs:0.95)}, anchor=near ticklabel,
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    ]
    \addplot[
    domain=-2:2,
    samples=100,
    ] {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

The `every axis x label` sets the axis description position regardless of whether the axis is boxed or non boxed (comment out `axis x line` to see this). There's a `every non boxed x axis` key, but I believe this is for the axis line, not the description. I wasn't able to find a `every non boxed axis x label` key, or something similar. Of course, I could do this on a case-by-case basis (which is what I've been doing), but I'd prefer to make this a default. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you put the `every axis x label` style inside the `every non boxed x axis`, it works. And duplicate it in `every non boxed y axis` as well, if you want that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\pgfplotsset{%
every non boxed x axis/.style={
  every axis x label/.style={%
    at={(ticklabel cs:0.95)}, anchor=near ticklabel,
  },
},
every non boxed y axis/.style={
  every axis x label/.style={%
    at={(ticklabel cs:0.95)}, anchor=near ticklabel,
  },
},
width=7cm, height=3cm % just for example
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    ]
    \addplot[
    domain=-2:2,
    samples=100,
    ] {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    ]
    \addplot[
    domain=-2:2,
    samples=100,
    ] {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    axis y line=left,
    ]
    \addplot[
    domain=-2:2,
    samples=100,
    ] {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Any chance you could explain just a little about why this works? Are nested options like this discussed somewhere in the manual? I was playing around with this a bit and noticed that setting the x axis label option in the non boxed y axis option created the effect for the x axis when the y axis was non boxed. In other words, it doesn't appear that the nested option needs to be related to the parent option. Instead, the nested option is only invoked when the parent option is invoked. Is this correct?

Comment: @MattHusz If I understand correctly, yes. The description of the `every non boxed x axis` style say "A style which will be installed as soon as `axis x line` will be set to something different than `box`." And similar for `y`. So whatever you put  in that style gets activated when you do e.g. `axis x line=bottom`.